# SQL inheritance performance

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, where-clause

In a SQL database (MySQL, to be more concrete) there's a table where it's rows can have two meanings.

To get into context, the table represents the state of a game. Then each row might be a saved state game or a initial game state (representing the levels).

I have a bit of discussion with my team mate, about how to design/implement this. I've allways being told that doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE games (
    id INT,
    PRIMARY_KEY (id)
)
CREATE TABLE levels (
    id INT,
    PRIMARY_KEY (id),
    FOREIGN_KEY (id) REFERENCES games(id)
)
CREATE TABLE saved (
    id INT,
    PRIMARY_KEY (id),
    FOREIGN_KEY (id) REFERENCES games(id)
)
```

was "better" than doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE games (
    id INT,
    `type` ENUM('level', 'saved')
    PRIMARY_KEY (id)
)
```

In the first case, a fetch from the saves would be made with a "join", and in the second case would be with a "where type=level".

Then what's better, in both terms of design and in performance of the database?

We are more concerned about the performance, but we really don't know if join is much more slower than a simple select with a where.

Comment: It's not a matter of performance (well, not only). The basic thing is - that those structures point to different relationship and you need to decide which fits your application's logic

Comment: But even if there's different relationships between these two types (levels and saved), it can be put everything in a single table making the columns optional (NULL-able). So 'levels' rows would have some columns to null, and 'saved' would have others. This would be "ok"? Does it increase or decrease the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In term of performance there are several parameters to take into account and the first one is to know how big is the volume of data you want to store, if you only have few hundreds of entries you'll not notice big differences between these two approaches.

The real question is much more about your needs. If you need for example to store information about the different `levels` (name, difficulty,...) the second solution is clearly not an option because! Same situation if you want to store information about a saved occurrence (date, progression in the game,...).

Think about the needs before thinking about the way to build the query that will return the result you want.

Hope this will help you to better understand the approach to adopt when you need to design a database structure.

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry for not having updated this. Finally we used the multiple-table approach, as we had many other relationships and specific columns in each type, and I really didn't like having NULL-able columns, as my partner said (I won the discussion \*teehee\*)